# Injecting a service into another class - Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a injectable service called ApiEndpoint. I need to use this service inside of another class, however i am facing issues.

The code goes something like this:

```
//apiEndpoint.ts
@Injectable()
export class ApiEndpoint {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  createGroup() { this._http...) 
}
```

//group.ts

```
import {ApiEndpoint} from './apiEndpoint';

  export class Group {
    public name: string;

    constructor(){}

    save(){
       ApiEndpoint.createGroup();  <== ERROR
    }
  }
```

Few places we import 'group.ts' and do the following

```
let myGroup = new Group();
 myGroup.name = 'foo';
 myGroup.save();
```

I receive the following error:

```
Property 'createGroup' does not exist on type 'typeof ApiEndpoint'.
```

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createGroup()` is an instance method, and you're trying to use it as a static method. Use dependency injection:

```
export class Group {
    public name: string;

    constructor(private apiEndpoint; ApiEndpoint ){}

    save() {
       this.apiEndpoint.createGroup();
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class GroupFactory {
    constructor(private apiEndpoint: ApiEndpoint) {}

    createGroup() {
        return new Group(this.apiEndpoint);
    }
}
```

Then inject GroupFactory in components that need to create groups, and use

```
let myGroup = this.groupFactory.createGroup();
myGroup.name = 'foo';
myGroup.save();
```